# KSH error line 26: syntax error at line 41: `done' unexpected

Tags: ksh

Keep getting that issue when I enter more then 1 parameter like so on terminal:

./learn 1 2

I concluded its from the while loop but commenting stuff out hasn't got to the cause.

```
#!/bin/ksh
#
count=$#

if test $count -lt 1
then
    echo "Enter at least 1 number"
    exit
elif test $count -gt 9
then
    echo "Enter max 9 numbers"
    exit
else
    echo "Parameter check: PASSED"
fi

set -A numbers $@
first=${numbers[0]}

if test $count -eq 1
then
    echo "$first = $first"
    exit
else
    sum=$first
    printf "$first + "
fi

while test "$count" -gt 1
do
    shift
    first=${numbers[0]}
    ((sum = sum + first))
    if test $count -gt 2
    then
    printf "$first + "
    else
    printf "$first = $sum"
    fi
    ((count = count - 1)
done
```

Its basically a program that takes in user inputs...i.e 1 2 3 from screen and adds together to give a sum

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line before `done`,

```
((count = count - 1)
```

has two opening but only one closing brace.

Comment: @Bobski: Consider using http://shellcheck.net in the future; it would have detected your problem.